# Как правильно прописать access list для доступа к серверу от разных пользователей в Cisco Packet Tracer 2013?

Tags: cisco-packet-tracer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне обеспечить доступ к серверу только от администрации то есть от VLAN4
знаю что надо создавать access list но я не понимаю как правильно их прописывать.
адрес в VLAN4 слева - 192.168.4.0/24
VLAN2 - 192.168.2.0/24
VLAN3 - 192.168.3.0/24
и мои счетные попытки это сделать но не получается как надо получается либо запретить все либо ничего не выходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
заранее спасибо